# Checking if value exists in pandas row, and if so, in which columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm iterating over rows of a pandas DataFrame that looks like this :

```
         col0      col1      col2
0       False     False     False
1       False     False      True
2       False      True     False
3       False      True      True
4        True     False     False
5        True     False      True
6        True      True     False
7        True      True      True
8       False      True      True
9        True      True     False
```

I'd like a way to, for each row, get the column number of the columns that are true :

So here, the output would look something like :

```
1 col2
2 col1
3 col1
3 col2
4 col0
5 col0
5 col2
6 col0
6 col1
7 col0
7 col1
7 col2
8 col1
8 col2
9 col0
9 col1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `np.where`

```
i, j = np.where(df)
pd.Series(df.columns[j], df.index[i])

1    col2
2    col1
3    col1
3    col2
4    col0
5    col0
5    col2
6    col0
6    col1
7    col0
7    col1
7    col2
8    col1
8    col2
9    col0
9    col1
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 4):

By using `mul`

```
df.mul(df.columns).replace('',np.nan).stack().reset_index(level=1,drop=True)
Out[122]: 
1    col2
2    col1
3    col1
3    col2
4    col0
5    col0
5    col2
6    col0
6    col1
7    col0
7    col1
7    col2
8    col1
8    col2
9    col0
9    col1
dtype: object
```

From piR

```
df.mul(df.columns).where(df).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
```

Comment: Also, add this.  `df.mul(df.columns).where(df).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)`

Comment: @piRSquared yeah !! forget the mask (where)

Comment: Not sure why you lost an upvote!  Just so everyone else is aware, this is a very good pandas answer.

Comment: @piRSquared that is ok :-)

Answer (score 2):

List comprehension can be used here with list of column names and df values as list of lists:

```
outlist = [ [i, df.columns.tolist()[j]]
        for i,r in enumerate(df.values)
        for j,c in enumerate(r)
        if c ]

print(outlist)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 'col2'], [2, 'col1'], [3, 'col1'], [3, 'col2'], [4, 'col0'], [5, 'col0'], [5, 'col2'], [6, 'col0'], [6, 'col1'], [7, 'col0'], [7, 'col1'], [7, 'col2'], [8, 'col1'], [8, 'col2'], [9, 'col0'], [9, 'col1']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to do it, it seems ugly, but hey `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

```
for rownumber, values in my_dataframe.iterrows():
    for colnumber, value in enumerate(list(values)):
        if value == True:
            print(rownumber, my_dataframe.columns[colnumber])
```

Comment: I applaud the effort, but this is an unnecessary double loop and would be considered by some to antithetical to pandas.